# Marshal Go Struct to BSON for mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, go, marshalling, bson, mongoimport

I have a slice of structs that I want to write to a BSON file for doing a `mongoimport`.

This a rough idea of what I'm doing (using `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson`):

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string `bson:"_id"`
    Text string `bson:"text"`
}

items := []Item{
    {
        ID: "abc",
        Text: "def",
    },
    {
        ID: "uvw",
        Text: "xyz",
    },
}

file, err := bson.Marshal(items)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to marshal BSON file: '%s'", err.Error())
}

if err := ioutil.WriteFile("test.bson", file, 0644); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to write BSON file: '%s'", err.Error())
}
```

This runs and generates the file, but it's not formatted correctly - instead it looks like this (using `bsondump --pretty test.bson`):

```
{
    "1": {
        "_id": "abc",
        "text": "def"
    },
    "2": {
        "_id": "abc",
        "text": "def"
    }
}
```

When I think it should look more like:

```
{
    "_id": "abc",
    "text": "def"
{
}
    "_id": "abc",
    "text": "def"
}
```

Is this possible to do in Go? I just want to generate a `.bson` file that you would expect a `mongodump` command to produce, so that I can run `mongoimport` and populate a colection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want independent BSON documents, so marshal the items individually:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
for _, item := range items {
    data, err := bson.Marshal(item)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to marshal BSON item: '%v'", err)
    }
    buf.Write(data)
}

if err := ioutil.WriteFile("test.bson", buf.Bytes(), 0644); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to write BSON file: '%v'", err)
}
```

Running `bsondump --pretty test.bson`, the output will be:

```
{
        "_id": "abc",
        "text": "def"
}
{
        "_id": "uvw",
        "text": "xyz"
}
2022-02-09T10:23:44.886+0100    2 objects found
```

Note that the buffer is not needed if you write directly to the file:

```
f, err := os.Create("test.bson")
if err != nil {
    log.Panicf("os.Create failed: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()

for _, item := range items {
    data, err := bson.Marshal(item)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("bson.Marshal failed: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err := f.Write(data); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("f.Write failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of context, but how does one do Unmarshal ?

Comment: @ekchom By calling `bson.Unmarshal()` instead of `bson.Marshal()`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.  This specific question has 'Slice' Marshalled. To Un Marshal,  out parameter needs to be passed, it cant be 'Slice' or native Object(type) ?  What it should be. In crux, how to Un Marshal data, which has been marshalled in the answers above.

Comment: @ekchom Please read the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Unmarshal): _"Unmarshal deserializes data from in into the out value. The out value must be a map, a pointer to a struct, or a pointer to a bson.D value."_

Comment: @ekchom The code in the answer marshals `Item` struct values. To unmarshal, `out` must be a pointer to `Item`, that is `*Item`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250266/discussion-between-ekchom-and-icza).